# Scroll down automatically to an xpath element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-serenity

I have seen this code to go to a specific element.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Value"));
    Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable)element).getCoordinates(); 
    coordinate.onPage(); 
    coordinate.inViewPort();
```

I'm trying to implement this in my code, but when appears a message in the driver as it shows in the picture. Am I doing something wrong? 
maybe I have to import a package or create an instance?

I will appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: add the driver as a parameter into the function : `public void func(WebDriver driver)`

Answer (score 0):

try to do it with JavaScript:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false);", element);
```